# Fast numpy way to multiply non-zero elements in array

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array consisting of zeros and positive elements, I want to take the product of the non-zero elements. I am currently replacing zeroes with 1's `a[a == 0] = 1` and using `np.prod`. Given that my array is sparse, one speed up I assume would be to subset for non-zero elements `sub = a[a != 0]` and take the product over the elements in `sub`.
Is there a more efficient numpy operation to do do this?

Comment: `a.prod(where=a!=0)` should be faster. Without further information about `dtype` and approximate size, it is just a guess. Please always include a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your idea is correct, but it could be shortened to one line code like this:

```
np.prod(x[x != 0])
```